# Apple PDFKit - issue with PDFs with validation scripts.

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, ios-pdfkit, apple-pdfkit

I have a set of PDF files which have a few validations embedded into it using JavaScript. Validations like a date or time format, total getting calculated from various fields etc.

I have tested these PDF and they work good on Mac Chrome browser, on Windows Chrome browser, Windows Adobe Reader and on iPad Adobe Reader. However, same does not work on iPad when using Apple PDFKit to render the PDF in a `PDFView`. It does not validate, format any of the fields or give a popup validation error how it does in the iPad Adobe Reader App. For testing purpose, I am keeping this pdf in the applications and accessing it directly from there.

Is it possible to get the same functionality as the iPad Adobe Reader App where we get validation errors/popup when something is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the built in PDF viewer in iOS is very limited, it can't run JavaScript, probably for security purposes.

For a recent project we used Foxit's PDF SDK for iOS, I believe it has its own JS engine so it will run all of the scripts in your PDF.